# Set NODE_ENV from Grunt task

Tags: node.js, webpack, gruntjs, grunt-shell

I would like to set the NODE_ENV variable at the beginning of a Grunt task, to `development` or `production`, but it looks it's not as simple as I thought.

The reason, why I would like this is that I use grunt-webpack, which expects NODE_ENV to be set correctly to "development" or "production". But I also would like to initialize my tasks exclusively from grunt, if possible.

I created the following test Gruntfile, using the [grunt-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-shell) and [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) modules:

```
function log(err, stdout, stderr, cb, e) {
    if (err) {
        cb(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
    console.log(stdout);
    cb();
}

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        shell: {
            dev: {
                command : 'cross-env NODE_ENV="development"',
                options: {
                    callback: log
                }
            },
            dist: {
                command : 'cross-env NODE_ENV="production"',
                options: {
                    callback: log
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

};
```

Line 6 of log() should echo the actual value of process.env.NODE_ENV, but it constantly says `undefined`, even if I check it manually in the node console.

If I set it manually from the terminal, like `set NODE_ENV=production` (`set` is for Windows), everywhere echoes the value `production`, as I would like it to.

Comment: Why you just don't do `process.env.NODE_ENV='...'`?

Comment: @ponury-kostek Please clarify! :-)

Comment: Ok, sorry my mistake :(

Comment: `cross-env` I'm just using because of the local windows environment, `command : 'NODE_ENV="production"',` also fails when trying on the server.

Comment: clarification your question doesn't mention it but your bounty does -- you are using grunt-webpack correct? and have you looked at [grunt-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-env) by chance?

Comment: @aug Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am using grunt-webpack, updated the question. I tried with [grunt-env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env) as well, but that also didn't work. I've even found an issue with the same problem: [Not working · Issue #43 · jsoverson/grunt-env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env/issues/43)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test won't work because [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) runs a [child_process](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell/blob/master/tasks/shell.js#L43) and your callback runs after it ends and under the main process.
Same thing would happen with [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env).

If you want to pass an environment variable to `grunt-shell`, you should use the [options](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell#option-passed-to-the-exec-method) configuration according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).
For example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        dev: {
            command : 'echo %NODE_ENV%', //windows syntax
            options: {
                execOptions: {
                    env: {
                        'NODE_ENV': 'dev'
                    }
                },
                callback: log
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This will still print `undefined` for `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but the value of `NODE_ENV` will be available in the `stdout` because of the `echo`.

On a side note, it sounds like you're trying to run a process (`grunt-shell`), which runs a process (`cross-env`), which runs a process (`webpack` or `grunt-webpack`).
Why not just use the `cross-env` [example usage](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env#usage)? It looks pretty close to what you need.
Or you can just define the variable in the task [config](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/grunt-webpack#webpack) itself and lose all of these wrappers.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I accept it as an answer, as it already made a lot of things clearer to me.

But regarding to your answer, it looks to me that it is not possible to do what I want, is it? I mean, I see that I can add a script to package.json's scripts field, which sets the `NODE_ENV` to what I want and starts a grunt-task, but it's impossible to set the `NODE_ENV` *in a grunt task* and use it immediately in another grunt task, because `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be still `undefined`. Am I right?

Comment: @bencergazda it depends. If you set `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside the grunt task it will work for as long as grunt doesn't create another `child_process` to run an additional task. In your example you use `grunt-shell` which does this and that's why it didn't work. But if you use `grunt-webpack` directly, it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

LifeQuery's answer helped me a lot to find out what the problem actually was. I first realized that `webpack.DefinePlugin()` actually [doesn't change anything](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2121#issuecomment-209630944) on `process.env.NODE_ENV` (and it would be too late anyway, as it transforms code parsed by webpack after all loaders).

After this I created a solution, which does what I want. This is how my customized Gruntfile.js begins:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Setting the node environment based on the tasks's name or target
    let set_NODE_ENV = function () {
        const devTasks = ['webpack-dev-server', 'dev', 'hmr', 'watch'],
            devTargets = [':dev'],
            task = grunt.cli.tasks[0], // The name of the (first) task we initialized grunt with ('webpack-dev-server' if started 'grunt webpack-dev-server)
            target = ':'+grunt.option('target'),
            devEnv = (devTasks.indexOf(task) > -1 || devTargets.indexOf(target) > -1);

        process.env.NODE_ENV = devEnv ? 'development' : 'production';
    }();

    const webpackConfig = require('../assets/webpack.config');

    grunt.initConfig({
        // ...usual Gruntfile content
    });

};
```

I created a whitelist of grunt task names and targets when I set the `process.env.NODE_ENV`. As it is placed before the `grunt.initConfig()`, the configuration object can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` with the desired state.

It will set `NODE_ENV` to "development" if starting definitely `webpack-dev-server`, `dev`, `hmr` or `watch` tasks, or any other tasks with the `:dev` target.